# I'm making a racing game with python turtle graphics and I got problem

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I try to make turtles turn around at x 540.
I make gamestart to be operated when spacebar pressed
but If a run this code and press spacebar, only blue_turtle moves.
Would anybody help me to solve this problem or write code to make
turtles turn around?

ps. I set blue_turn ~ green_turn 0.

```
def gamestart():
    global blue_turn, pink_turn, yellow_turn, green_turn

    while blue_turtle.xcor() < 540:
        blue_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        blue_turtle.forward(randint(1, 8))
    if blue_turtle.xcor() >= 540:
        blue_turtle.tilt(180)
        blue_turn += 1
    while blue_turn > 0:
        blue_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        blue_turtle.backward(randint(1, 8))

    while pink_turtle.xcor() < 540:
        pink_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        pink_turtle.forward(randint(1, 8))
    if pink_turtle.xcor() >= 540:
        pink_turtle.tilt(180)
        pink_turn += 1
    while pink_turn > 0:
        pink_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        pink_turtle.backward(randint(1, 8))

    while yellow_turtle.xcor() < 540:
        yellow_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        yellow_turtle.forward(randint(1, 8))
    if yellow_turtle.xcor() >= 540:
        yellow_turtle.tilt(180)
        yellow_turn += 1
    while yellow_turn > 0:
        yellow_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        yellow_turtle.backward(randint(1, 8))

    while green_turtle.xcor() < 540:
        green_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        green_turtle.forward(randint(1, 8))
    if green_turtle.xcor() >= 540:
        green_turtle.tilt(180)
        green_turn += 1
    while green_turn > 0:
        green_turtle.speed(randint(0, 4))
        green_turtle.backward(randint(1, 8))
```

Comment: simple solution: use a single while loop for all turtle logic. More complex, use threads

Comment: but sorry I can't do that

Comment: because if I use a single while loop, if one reach x 540, the others stop

Comment: should or will stop? you can exit while loops early

Comment: it should not stop and still should reach x 540. I solved this tho. Thank you for your comment!